# Excel Index-Match function to get the header of column based on item in column

Tags: excel-formula

let's say I have some data in Excel that looks like this :
[image]

Now, in another cell (let's say a drop down menu or something else) there will be the name of an item from a Category;Ex: in cell E3 I will type (or select) 'Item3'.
**I want to display the header of the column that contains item3 (which is Category A).If it was item7 or item8 the result should be Category C**

[image]

But I get a #N/A, here's the formula for the result:

```
=INDEX(A1:C1,,MATCH(E2,A2:C5,0))
```

Where:

```
A1:C1 => Columns Header 
E2 => The cell where the item whose category I want to find
A2:C5 => All Items, where to Match the item from E2
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE not MATCH.  MATCH only wants a single column or row, not a two dimensional range.

```
=INDEX(1:1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A2:C5)/(A2:C5 = E2),1))
```